# Navigation inside this or currentTarget

Tags: javascript, dom

I have short question about DOM navigation.

I know that you can navigate to parent elements with for ex:
event.currentTarget.parentElement or this.parentElement

but i am strugguling to find solution to navigate to child elements when using this or for ek event.currentTarget

Could somebody send me in right direction so i can read more about solutions for this?

thank you in advance

Comment: `element.querySelector(...)` or `element.children`

Comment: Or [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) if you need to work with the text contents or comments of an element as well.

Comment: @DM You can work with the text contents via `.querySelector()` and `.children`.

Comment: i am using it in exemple with click event where i have e.currentTarget and trying to get to a specific class inside this event user has clicked on. The point is to change that class to something else with classList. I managed to do it with children (and than specific index). Is it mayby other ways to do this?
Thank you very much for your answers :)